# Frustrating, nonsensical assembly reference errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reference, assemblies

I've recently completed a (hopefully successful) VB to C# conversion on a decent-sized library. However, I am receiving some trouble from the compiler when trying to build it. I created a small helper library called `ExtensionMethods`, compiled it, dropped the .dll in the `bin` folder of the outlying project, and added a reference to it in the newly-converted library. The library has two namespaces, `ExtensionMethods.Json` and `ExtensionMethods.Enums`. In any class where I want to use the `Enums` namespace, I import it with `using ExtensionMethods.Enums`. I do the same for the `.Json` namespace (which works fine, by the way).

The following is picture evidence of what is happening:

[image]

Notice the blue squiggle under `Enums` with a simultaneous suggestion for `Enums` from Intellisense. Here is proof that VS actually recognizes the assembly (`.ToInt()` is the name of the extension method):

[image]

Notice how `.ToInt()` is both suggested by Intellisense as an extension method AND does not have a squiggle under it, even though ALLEGEDLY...

[image]
(three files use this namespace)

which would make sense, except for...

[image]

Essentially, what this is saying is that, "Yes, Jason, you have referenced all your assemblies correctly, yes, your assemblies contain the namespaces they should, but no, I don't feel like compiling today."

I just want to compile and be done with this monster. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

`ExtensionMethods.Json`, another namespace in `ExtensionMethods` works fine when referenced and does not produce an assembly reference error. Both projects were created on the same 64-Bit machine and everything targets .NET 4.

Comment: I've seen this before... trying to remember how I resolved it, but it wasn't anything that I was doing wrong... VS was just being stupid

Comment: Are both projects targeting the same version of the .NET framework?  

Is there somewhere you could upload a sample project that is doing this for you?

Comment: Both projects target .NET 4. What's weird is that `ExtensionMethods.Json` works fine, but `.Enums` just isn't being recognized...

Comment: What are the 2 warnings saying?

Comment: @richard ha, those are just "code not returning a value on all the code paths" warnings in the VB version of the project.

Comment: Who is doing the compiling? VS or some custom task? Do you have custom post/pre build events? etc?

Comment: @noon I'm just hitting "Build" > "Build [my project]". No custom anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's how I fixed it. Basically I went and deleted .DLL from my bin folder, deleted every reference to it, dropped the .DLL back in, and re-referenced everything. Now, for some strange reason, that compilation problem is gone. Yay.

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember something like this when I was struggling with a 64 vs 32 bit problem. Make sure the reference is usable by your project's platform. If I'm remembering correctly, I was referencing a 32-bit DLL in a project that was compiled for "Any CPU" on a 64-bit platform, or something of the sort, this was a while ago.

Comment: both projects were built on the same 64bit machine. One part of the `ExtensionMethods` assembly works, the other doesn't :(

Answer (score 0):

Only way to solve this I found when I had the same problem was commenting out all that and related code, removing the references, re-build all, adding the reference again and uncommenting the code, re-build.

note: re-build, not build... and just re-adding the reference doesn't help

It seems the builder gets an invalid partial build or something (don't know how it technically works) that it won't overwrite even if you tell it to re-build. You need to get rid of all the code and references and re-build to get rid of the invalid state.

(yes I know, it's a lot of work and it sucks, but it's the only way I found to get rid of it)